# NSHTTPCookieStorage does not save cookie automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies, nshttpcookie, nshttpcookiestorage

I'm recieving cookie in `Set-Cookie` header of NSURLResponse, but `[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]` returns empty list. `NSHTTPCookie`, which i received from response, is `HTTPOnly`, secure and has no `expiresDate`. What can be reason of this behaviour of `NSHTTPCookieStorage`?

**UPDATE:**

I've checked `NSHTTPCookieStorage` accept policy right before request was sent and after response was received. It was `NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways` , however, cookie wasn't been stored. If i send another request, that returns another cookie, storage automatically saves it. That cookie has expiration date and not `HTTPOnly`, so, i think, the problem is somewhere in cookie's properties, but i can't find any confirmation in documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what's the problem. Cookie was not stored automatically, because cookie domain and request/response domain are different.